# Touchpad not working on Lenovo IdeaPad 520 with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, ideapad

I tried reinstalling and updating synaptic. It's all up to date. Initially this laptop came with Windows and the touchpad was working fine on that.